# Python Peewee execute_sql() example

Tags: python, sql, database, peewee

I am using the Peewee module as the ORM for my project.

I read the entire documentation, there is no clear
example on how to process the result from db.execute_sql().

I traced the code, only can find db.execute_sql() return back the cursor.

Does anyone knows how to process the cursor, such as iterate over it and get
back the result from complex select statement.

Update: I just found the following source code from peewee folder, it should help
me to resolve this problem.

```
class QueryResultWrapper(object):
    """
    Provides an iterator over the results of a raw Query, additionally doing
    two things:
    - converts rows from the database into python representations
    - ensures that multiple iterations do not result in multiple queries
    """
    def __init__(self, model, cursor, meta=None):
        self.model = model
        self.cursor = cursor

        self.__ct = 0
        self.__idx = 0

        self._result_cache = []
        self._populated = False
        self._initialized = False

        if meta is not None:
            self.column_meta, self.join_meta = meta
        else:
            self.column_meta = self.join_meta = None

    def __iter__(self):
        self.__idx = 0

        if not self._populated:
            return self
        else:
            return iter(self._result_cache)

    def process_row(self, row):
        return row

    def iterate(self):
        row = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if not row:
            self._populated = True
            raise StopIteration
        elif not self._initialized:
            self.initialize(self.cursor.description)
            self._initialized = True
        return self.process_row(row)

    def iterator(self):
        while True:
            yield self.iterate()

    def next(self):
        if self.__idx  self.__ct):
            try:
                self.next()
            except StopIteration:
                break
```

Comment: What is the type of the object returned? Run `sql_execute()` and print the result to see it's type.

Answer (score 37):

Peewee returns a cursor.  Then you can use the db-api 2 to iterate over it:

```
cursor = db.execute_sql('select * from tweets;')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)

cursor = db.execute_sql('select count(*) from tweets;')
res = cursor.fetchone()
print('Total: ', res[0])
```

Docs: [`Database.execute_sql`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.execute_sql)

Comment: is there a fetch that returns a dictionary which maps column name?

Comment: @SagarShah It have to be mapped to a Class with given table name and field, how's about some query like `show table status from db_name` ? It maps to none table

Comment: @KJW Try using the `cursor.description` to grab the column names: 

`col_names = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
res = [dict(zip(col_names, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]`