# loop through peewee results in flask

Tags: python, flask, peewee

based on this reply:

```
cursor = db.execute_sql('select * from tweets;')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row

cursor = db.execute_sql('select count(*) from tweets;')
res = cursor.fetchone()
print 'Total: ', res[0]
```

from: [Python Peewee execute_sql() example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500956/python-peewee-execute-sql-example)

how to take it to flask app and then display in a webpage?

is this correct:

model.py

```
def get_statistics():
        cursor = finDB.execute_sql('CALL Allstatistics;')
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
                return row
```

app.py

```
@app.route("/finance")
def finance():
        stats = model.get_statistics()
        return render_template('/finance.html', stats=stats)
```

but how to display it in a table?

Comment: you want to display them in a html table?, please show how the stats  look like?  stats is for what data type?? a list? a dict?

Comment: Yes in HTML <table>, when I run this stored procedure directly in mysql, I get 6 columns and 22 rows:  text | -55585.73 | -24834.28 | -2069.94 |  -895.19 | NULL

Comment: What is the data structure of the results ?

Comment: I don't know... list?

Comment: I'm obviously not... in my peewee model:         def get_tags(self):
                return tag_list.select(), gives me output from the table, then in flask app.py I just do output = model.get_tags() and then in app route: @app.route(.... output=output...), then on a webpage I can loop through using column headers <td>{{ row.header }}</td> but none of this works with db.execute_sql() method.

Comment: `for row in cursor.fetchall(): return row` doesn't look quite right to me.

Comment: this is from other reply by @coliefer, and he designed it, so should know best...

Comment: @michal There is a difference, in his reply he `print` the rows in his loop... your function is supposed to `return` all rows, but will only return the first one.

Comment: @bgse, I've noticed this, but If I use print instead of return I get error when loading the page: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @michal See answer below for explanation of the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your adaption of:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row
```

This will print all the rows returned by `fetchall()`, one by one.

You tried to adapt this into a function `returning` all rows:

```
def get_statistics():
    cursor = finDB.execute_sql('CALL Allstatistics;')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        return row
```

Now this will `return` the first row only, as the return statement terminates your loop on first iteration.

What you really want is something like this:

```
def get_statistics():
    cursor = finDB.execute_sql('CALL Allstatistics;')
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

This will correctly return all rows in the cursor, or `None` if there are no result rows.

With checking if there is a non-empty result, and instead of `None` returning an empty list, you could do it this way:

```
def get_statistics():
    cursor = finDB.execute_sql('CALL Allstatistics;')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    if rows:
        return rows
    return []
```

Regarding `cursor.fetchone()`, this will return the next available row of the cursor, or `None` if no more rows are available. For example, you can iterate over all available rows in your cursor like this:

```
rows = []
row = cursor.fetchone() # fetch first row, or None if empty result
while row is not None:
    rows.append(row)
    row = cursor.fetchone() # fetch the next row, if None loop terminates
return rows # return all collected results
```

For your use-case, it might be interesting to construct a more convenient data structure for your result, e.g. a `list of dicts`:

```
rows = []
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    rows.append({'foo': row[0], 'bar': row[1], 'baz': row[2]})
    row = cursor.fetchone()
return rows
```

Note that this can be similarly achieved like this:

```
rows = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    rows.append({'foo': row[0], 'bar': row[1], 'baz': row[2]})
return rows
```

You can then write in your template, looping `for row in rows`:

```
foo is {{row['foo']}} and bar is {{row['bar']}}
```

Or you could construct a list of `namedtuple`, allowing you to write in template:

```
foo is {{row.foo}} and bar is {{foo.bar}}
```

Comment: The first option works ok with <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>. the second option crashes the app and highlights syntax error for rows=cursor.fetchall():. None of the options work for <td>{{row.ColumnHeader}}</td>

Comment: @michal The 2nd option had an extra `:` left over from a previous edit, sorry about that. None of these will work for `{{row.ColumnHeader}}` as each `row` is of type `list`, and will not have the fields as attributes named by column headers.

Comment: My bad, typo error, added ':' after fetchall(), both option works correctly, Thanks!

Comment: Can you take it one step further and explain fetchone() ? def get_stats_summary():
        cursor = finDB.execute_sql('call AllStatisticsSum()')
        return cursor.fetchone() then try to loop through no no thing is showing

Comment: @michal See edit, you can use `fetchone()` to fetch a single row from the cursor.

Comment: OK, I got it. in app.py: summary =  model.get_summary(), then on the web page {{ summary[0] }} {{ summary[1] }}

Comment: thanks for that, however if sql query returns only 1 row I feel its bad practice to loop through rows... as there is only and always 1 row

Comment: @michal Indeed, when you expect one and only one result, you'd probably even want to safeguard against `empty result` and `more than one result`.